# ASP.NET MVC 5 APP runs on local machine but does not run on remote machine ("The network path was not found")

Tags: asp.net, iis, model-view-controller, remote-server

I've got a problem with running the web app on a remote server. See the specification of this problem below:

The steps of publishing to remote server:
1. publish on local machine 
2. copy published files from local machine IIS folder and paste them to remote server's IIS folder
3. set remote server's folder permissions (sharing for Everyone)

On my local machine server (*IIS v 10.0.15063.0*) there's no problem.

The problem occurs when I try to run the application on the remote server (*IIS v 8.0.9200.16384*). The error message "**[The network path was not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCPEX.png)**" occurs.

The thing is, that I can successfully run other web app (very similar, even the Web.config file is same) on the same remote server.

Many thx for your effort to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was not allowed connectivity between application server (where my app is) and db server (where my app connects)

So our system admin had to allow connections between those servers. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happened because your website cannot connect to the database. You need to check `connectionString` setting in your web.config file

Comment: connectionString should be valid, because it's same as in another application.

Comment: The problem that your `remote server` cannot connect to DB, because of network or something. You need to check connection to DB from remote server

Comment: I am not able to ping the specific server from remote machine command line. But I don't get it because I have same connstrings in another app and as I said, that works...

Comment: May be your connection string hardcoded somewhere in code?

Comment: But if the problem is the connection to DB from remote machine, it does not matter if connstring is hardcoded or not, doesn't it? Every time the connection request come from remote->db. Am I right?

Comment: I mean in web.config you might have connection string to `server=1.1.1.1`, but in code it can be hardcoded to `server=localhost` and not reading from web.config

Comment: Yes, probably that was the problem I do not have the old app source files, so I can not guarantee it. But it seems as the problem like that. In the new application, our system admin had to allow connections between used servers. It solved my problem. Thx for help!